# How to write a binary stream buffer into a file in Python 3 without explicitly read from it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, buffer

I have a file that I want to write bytes into from a binary stream buffer (either `io.BufferedReader` or `io.BytesIO`) without explicitly `read()` from it.

I cannot write its content to the file because `file.write()` only accepts [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object).

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
import io

read_buffer = io.BytesIO(b'buffer bytes content')

with open('target_file', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(read_buffer)
    # file.write(read_buffer.read()) is not a solution
```

I prefer to use either Python's built-in modules or external Python package to handle it.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do using [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)

```
import io
import shutil    

read_buffer = io.BytesIO(b'buffer content 1')

with open('target_file', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(read_buffer, file)
```